# Python Time and Date objects use 24-hour clock even though PM is declared in time format

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Both time.strptime and datetime.strptime give results in 24-hour clock even though I indicated a 12 hour clock in the time format string.  I used it and I noticed it doesn't respect my PM notations (stores 9PM as 9AM), even though the time format is correctly set.

Example:

```
format = "%I:00PM"
mytime = "09:00PM"
x = time.strptime(mytime, format)
print x
```

Outputs

> time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=9, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)

This is wrong! tm_hour is 9 in this case, it should have been 21.

If I try

```
y = datetime.strptime(mytime,format)
print y
```

I get

> 1900-01-01 09:00:00

Again very wrong.

The time segment should have been 21 (9PM), not 9AM.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it through a string? Also, are you trying to convert it to a `datetime.time` object, a `datetime.datetime` object (those are not the same type!), or something different? You seem to contradict yourself throughout the question.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry if it seemed confusing. I simply wanted to save a time object from a string while respecting the AM PM differences. I actually only made a mistake in the format. Should have been "%I:00%p" not "%I:00PM"

Comment: Even after that comment, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. What does "save a time object" mean? If it's being saved "from a string", where does `struct_time` even come into it? And how is `datetime` involved?

Comment: Let's clarify this: Exactly what type of date/time/whatever object are you getting from whatever your input is? Exactly what type do you need for whatever your output (or logic) is? What are all the other types used, mentioned, and implied in your question there for?

Comment: @abarnert The problem was caused by Django confusing me with its datetypes. The TimeField() model is a datetime.time object, and in my application I have to handle times as strings like "09:00PM", so when trying to save an entry to the database, Django complains about using time.strptime (which gives back a time.struct_time), and accepts datetime.strptime, which gives back a datetime.datetime object, not a datetime.time object. A bit confusing.

Comment: Why does your application need to handle times as strings? Why not handle them as times (or datetimes) everywhere (except of course for rendering them to strings in the UI template)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do what you are trying to do but you can use the format

```
import time
mytime = "09:00PM"
time.strptime(mytime, '%I:00%p')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=21, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

`%p` formatting instead of `'PM'` string

Comment: Yes, I just figured it, and I was about to answer my own question but you beat me to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to convert through string, and it's almost guaranteed to cause problems.

Let's try this:

```
tm = time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=4, tm_hour=15, tm_min=52, tm_sec=25, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=94, tm_isdst=1)
dt = datetime.datetime(tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)
```

But you may notice that we're using the first 6 members of `struct_time` in the same order they appear in that struct. And `struct_time` is actually a `namedtuple` or something that acts just like one. So really, just:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(*tm[:6])
```

If you want a `time` object instead of a `datetime`, that's easy. Either of these:

```
t = datetime.time(tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)
t = datetime.datetime(*tm[:6]).time()
```

Meanwhile, if you don't know the difference between naive and aware dates, read the introduction to the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) docs. A `struct_time` is always naive, and the `datetime` you construct this way will also be naive. You have to externally keep track of whether it's a local time, a UTC time, or a local time from some other timezone. If you mix it up, you'll get problems like thinking it's 1:00 when it's actually 10:00 or vice-versa.

Comment: I actually have a need to convert from string to time (through time.strptime) so what kind of problems am I expecting here, considering that I'm only using one timezone?

Comment: Your code was using `datetime.strptime`, not `time.strptime`. And your question said you wanted to "convert a time.struct_time to a datetime object" and asked "how do I convert a time.struct_time object to time?", so converting from string to time shouldn't even enter into it.

Comment: I posted two examples, one using datetime.strptime and one using time.strptime, with both showing a mistake due to the time format being wrong. The reason it sounds confusing is because that's how Django deals with TimeField(). The docs say it is datetime.time, but when you save it, it wants a datetime.datetime.